# Column invalid error in MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is tracking "Patient Days" or, patients (csn_id) that come in and leave the same day.  This happens in one of two ways

1. admit and discharge with an event type of 1
2. automatic same day discharge with event type 6

Everything looked good until I added my Group By statement.  I've read the other question posts that received the same "Msg 8120" but I'm not sure how I resolve this and am open to any/all suggestions.

```
SELECT
 '1,*'+char(13)+char(10)
+'80,1006057'+char(13)+char(10)
+'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
+'2405,'+cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)
+'2420,'+format(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'M/d/yyyy') --as efftime
FROM CLARITY_ADT adt
inner join PAT_ENC_HSP hsp on adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID=hsp.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
WHERE adt.EVENT_SUBTYPE_C <>2 AND --no canelled events
       datediff(day,adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)) between 1 and 7 AND

  ((adt.EVENT_TYPE_C ='6' AND
    adt.DEPARTMENT_ID in ('101000020', '101000021', '101000013', '101000014', '101000002',
                         '101000018', '101000003', '101000114', '101000005', '101000017',
                         '101000006', '101000118', '101000007', '101000016', '101000004',
                         '101000009', '101000010', '101000011', '101000022', '101000023',
                         '101000012')) OR
  (cast(hsp.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME as date) = cast(hsp.HOSP_DISCH_TIME as date) AND
   adt.EVENT_TYPE_C ='1' AND
   adt.DEPARTMENT_ID in ('101000020', '101000021', '101000013', '101000014', '101000002',
                         '101000018', '101000003', '101000114', '101000005', '101000017',
                         '101000006', '101000118', '101000007', '101000016', '101000004',
                         '101000009', '101000010', '101000011', '101000022', '101000023',
                         '101000012')))

group by cast(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME as date)
order by cast(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME as date)
```

Comment: What is the type of EFFECTIVE_TIME column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `group by`, the only thing you're allowed to have in the query results is either the group itself, or aggregations like `max` or `sum`.

You're grouping by `cast(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME as date)`, but your query contains `format(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'M/d/yyyy')` - although these may logically be equivalent, they're not the same thing, so SQL Server is going to tell you that it's no good.

You can put `format(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'M/d/yyyy')` in your `group by`, or what would probably be better would be to put the date into the query, then wrap that with an outer query to format your result:

```
select
    '1,*'+char(13)+char(10)
    +'80,1006057'+char(13)+char(10)
    +'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
    +'2405,'+cast(num_records as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)
    +'2420,'+format(the_date,'M/d/yyyy') --as efftime
from
(
    select
        cast(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME as date) [the_date]
        ,count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) [num_records]
    FROM CLARITY_ADT adt
    WHERE ... /* where and join clauses */
    group by cast(adt.EFFECTIVE_TIME as date)
) x
order by x.the_date;
```

Comment: Great explanation - The format did the trick Joe - Thank you!

I agree with you on the outer query but I'm not very savvy with those and haven't had a lot of experience.  This seems to work so, I'm running with it.  Thanks again!